# Connect Redis though httpd or php.ini with user and tls

Tags: php, docker, apache, redis

Im triying to docker an php app web and i need to share the session to the differents node.
I was thinkin on redis to do that. The app is old and create the session with "$_SESSION" and with the function "session_start()". Is not viable modify that.

In other post, people use redis and connect in theirs php.ini or inside de httpd php.conf modifying  theirs "session.save_handler" and theirs "session.save_path".

I have externalized the redis server, and i want to connect it through php.ini changing the session save path and handler, the problem is i need to connect with an user, and there is no documentation to do it with an user, only with a local redis server and a password.

The server is active and i have connection. I was connected through redis cli. The app have connection because if i put the save path without user the app doesnt crash but without the user the app cant read or write, it need to auth inside redis to do that.

I tried different connections string inside the php.ini but it doesnt work.

This is an example of my php.ini ->

```
session.save_handler = redis
session.save_path = "redis://user:pass@IP:6379/0"
```

I tried with tcp and tls packets but is not working.
My server doesnt have a default user, because is not a self installation, is a hosted redis server.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.